# Camera Control via RS-422 Serial Port

Tags: python-3.x, camera, serial-port

I am currently doing research and writing a simple program in controlling a camera through the serial port, RS-422 to be more specific.  I got the camera control protocol documentation from the manufacturer.  I've been reading and testing for a few days now but unfortunately, I haven't managed to make it work.  I used Python (3.7) to speed up the testing.  Below is my sample code:

```
import serial

ser_port = serial.Serial(
    port='COM4',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    )

sccp_cmd_null = [0x00]
sccp_cmd = [0xE7, 0x40, 0x11, 0x43, 0x00, 0x00]  # Chroma Key "GREEN"

if ser_port.isOpen():
    # Try sending a break code first
    try:
        print("Sending Break Code: ", serial.to_bytes(sccp_cmd_null))
        ser_port.write(serial.to_bytes(sccp_cmd_null))
    except:
        print("Failed Sending Break Code!")


    # Try Sending The Commands
    try:
        print("Sending Commands: ", serial.to_bytes(sccp_cmd))
        ser_port.write(serial.to_bytes(sccp_cmd))
    except:
        print("Failed Sending Commands!")

ser_port.close()
```

Please note that this is my first time writing code that deals with Serial Ports.

Thank you in advanced for those who can provide help ^_^

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: @ewong hello, thank you for the kind words ^_^. There is actually no errors. Once I submitted the code, there is no reaction on the camera and even from python.

Comment: Do any of the debug messages print?  Does the program exit immediately?

Comment: Hi @mbedded, no, the debug messages are not being printed.

Comment: My best guess is that the serial port never opens, but I would expect that to raise an exception.  Try adding more debug messages at the very beginning and end of the script, and then just before the isOpen test.

Comment: @mbedded, thank you for the guidance ^_^ I ask the camera manufacturer and show them my code, the engineers mentioned that my packet construction is wrong.  He said, "Data next to each other must be sent in XOR form". I don't even know what that means since this is my first time interfacing a hardware.  Hope you can help me ^_^

Comment: This is from section 7 of the protocol doc.  Note that `^` is the xor operator in python, so your command frame should be: `sccp_cmd = [0xE7, 0xE7^0x40, 0x40^0x11, 0x11^0x43, 0x43^0x00, 0x00]`

Comment: @mbedded, ohhhhh that is the one I missed, now it works! Thank you very much ^_^